# Print the whole Xcode-project as a pdf for documentation-purpuose

Tags: xcode, documentation, printing, project

Is it possible to print all the source-files (and better also the class-model and .plists) in one step ?
I even cant find any other OS X-editor, that allows to print multiple files, but the project is relatively big to print each thing per hand.

To easily push the files to any printer-icon, what I have read, is not possible, because there is no printer installed - and a pdf-printer-icon does not exist, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Adobe Reader which should install the PDF Print drivers.